# IONIC 4 scroll to top when clicking on tab button

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic4

i need to scroll to the top of the page when i click a tab button and i am already in this page

**i tried:**

```
 @ViewChild(IonContent,  { static: false }) private content: IonContent;

myMethod() {
 this.content.scrollToTop();
}
```

but this does not work and i tried putting this in the `ioViewWillEnter` in the target page and still it only works for the first time in ionic 4

i also tried putting it in the `ionTabsDidChange` event of the ion tab but this event is only triggered if the tabs change

Comment: can you share stackblitz or just more code that can be worked on for solution?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko its a normal ionic 4 tabs i just need to scroll to top when i  press on a tab button if im in the same page as the selected tab, the code i added is the one in the question the rest is just the normal tabs that contains a grid or a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you've requested a tricky operation, as that is not the standard way of doing things.

Normally the button does nothing which makes the user realise they are already on that tab.

I set up a demo project and tried the different built-in events but ultimately the `tab-button` emits the `click` event and it gets as far as the `shouldChange` method in the `tabs` component before being dismissed for being the same tab:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/tabs/tabs.tsx#L164

What does work is adding a click event to your tab button in `tabs.page.html`:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    {{ snip }}

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2" (click)="tabButtonClicked('tab2')">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    {{ snip }}
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

I think by using that click handler you grab the current tab, and dispatch your own event:

```
tabButtonClicked(tabNumber: string) {
    if (tabNumber === this.selectTab) { 
        this.events.publish('tabs', tabNumber); 
    }
}
```

This guide shows how to use the Ionic Events system, which lets you pass custom events to other components in the system:

https://alligator.io/ionic/events/

So you can use this to emit a custom "scroll to top" event, and handle that inside the tab. Then use your original `.scrollToTop()` code inside that custom event handler.

For example in in the tab page you want to scroll add:

```
@ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) private content: IonContent; 

constructor(public events: Events) { 
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.events.subscribe('tabs', tabNumber => {
        if (tabNumber === 'tab1') { 
            this.content.scrollToTop(); 
        } 
    });
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.events.unsubscribe('tabs', () => {} );
}
```

Comment: thanks man , what i did  to make it work is is tabs.html 
<ion-tab-button tab="tab2" (click)="tabButtonClicked('tab2')">
in tabs.ts:
tabButtonClicked(tabNumber: string) {
  if (tabNumber === this.selectTab) {
    this.events.publish('tabs', tabNumber);
  }
}
and in page.ts :
  @ViewChild(IonContent,  { static: false }) private content: IonContent;
  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    public events: Events
  ) {
    this.events.subscribe('tabs', tabNumber => {
      if (tabNumber === 'tab1') {
        this.content.scrollToTop();
      }
    });
  }

Comment: actually I updated it a bit otherwise your events subscriptions will end up with memory leaks

Comment: if you agree it helped you, please consider upvoting this as well, otherwise stack overflow, in their wisdom, have decided this doesn't count towards my ionic4 tag badge.

Comment: yes i forgot to mention this but i did it in my code